# Return type of a `yield call`

Tags: typescript, redux-saga

I've noticed that the result of a `yield call` effect is typed as `any` when used as

```
const data = yield call(f);
```

while `f` is a `() => Promise<number>` function.

Am I missing something or is it a `redux-saga` typings limitation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check [this ongoing thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2983#issuecomment-230404301), tldr; it's a typescript limitation

Comment: Consider including the gist of the information in the link here as well.

Answer (score 5):

In the meantime, you can use this package instead: [`typed-redux-saga`](https://github.com/agiledigital/typed-redux-saga)

Before

```js
import { call, all } from "redux-saga/effects";
...
// Api.fetchUser return User
// but user has type any
const user = yield call(Api.fetchUser, action.payload.userId);
```

After

```js
import { call, all } from "typed-redux-saga";
...
// user now has the correct type User
// NOTE: it's yield*, not yield
const user = yield* call(Api.fetchUser, action.payload.userId);
```

Answer (score 1):

define this types

```
export type PromiseFn = (...args: any) => Promise<any>;
export type GetT<T> = T extends Promise<infer N> ? N : any;
export type GetFnResult<T extends PromiseFn> = GetT<ReturnType<T>>;
```

then

```
const data: GetFnResult<typeof f> = yield call(f);
```

Comment: My immediate "no" to any type declaration with `any`.

Comment: ReturnType use `any` also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
const data = (yield call(f)) as number
```

Comment: It's a lie to a compiler.

Comment: lying to compiler 